# Jetty use a servlet

Tags: maven, jetty, embedded-jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I am trying to make a jetty web app to display content from a template.
The code I have is a java file with the class that holds the information, a pom file, and a template.tpl file.
When I run mvn jetty:run, it spins up a server on port 8080 and points to the root od my web app folder.
How do I make it so when I type /template.tpl i can run java to fill the template?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you configured a `web.xml` file yet? [Here's](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/webapp/configureservlet.html) a guide on how to do this.
Basically in your `web.xml` file, you configure the Servlets you write and map them to matching urls.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the issue! I am new to jetty and servlets and i was completly lost, Thanks!